# Disadvantages of deploying by copying the excutable and .dll files (c# vs express)?

Tags: c#, deployment

I need to deploy an application. I don't need registry, so I thought about just copying the DLL and exe files to the client desktops (there are only three). What are the disadvantages of this in comparison to using clickonce deployment from a memory stick?

Comment: Your user isn't going to be pleased with a DLL on the desktop.  Of course she'll delete it.  Upgrade to the retail edition to move ahead, this is all trivial with a Setup project.

Comment: Why wouldn't my user like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get your add/remove programs integration, but if you're working on something that's very small and constrained, that might not be a big deal.  Are you concerned about something in particular that's prompting you to ask the question?

Comment: The add/remove programs stuff is likely the biggest concern.  If all you are doing is dumping files then the only way to get rid of the app is to delete those files.  Depending on your target user and whether they should be capable of removing the app this may not be a concern.

Comment: I don't have any specific concerns, I was just wondering if there are any advantages in my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

One main reason springs to mind- new versions. Assuming that the 3 PC's are networked, clickonce deployment to a server (not a memory stick) has the benefit of automagically checking for updates, downloading and installing new versions every time a user runs your app.